# Upgrading Apache, PHP and MySql in Vtiger 6.5 to migrate to Vtiger 7

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I was using the vtiger 5.4 and gradually upgraded to 6.5. Now when I tried to upgrade to vtiger 7, its showing the blank page. My version is not matching with the pre-requisites.

What I have the versions are as below:

```
PHP Version: 
C:\vtigercrm-5.4.0\php>php -v
PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May 2 2008 18:02:07)

mysql> select version();
+----------------------+
| version() |
+----------------------+
| 5.0.51b-community-nt |
+----------------------+

Apache Version:
C:\vtigercrm-5.4.0\apache\bin>Apache -v
Server version: Apache/2.0.52
```

How can I upgrade this to the next level, so that I can continue the Vtiger 7 migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no custom code of your own, I would suggest the following steps -

1. **Backup your code and database for 6.5**
2. Uninstall your vtiger 5.4 version
3. Install XAMPP with PHP7.1 support. Moving away from the standard vtiger installer will let you upgrade to future versions of PHP/apache without this hassle.
4. Import your database to this new XAMPP and setup the code (you will need to change the config.inc.php)

If everything goes fine, you should have your 6.5 version back working normally and you should be able to upgrade to vtiger 7.

Some pointers -

1. The new XAMPP installation will have different PHP/mysql settings
2. Check the Mysql UTF-8 support when creating db
3. **Don't panic** if you see lot of notice/warnings, it just means your php.ini is not configured properly yet

Comment: I have tried this. And this seems the simplest way of doing the upgrade. Thanks for your answer. Instead of XAMPP, I had used WAMP.